# How to calculate ${A_2n}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Actually I have such question :

N is a universal set. ${n \in N}$ and ${A_n = \{0, 1, 2, ... n\}}$

Expression is

$${\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (A_{2n} \setminus A_n)}$$

Is it equal to ${\varnothing, N \setminus \{0\}}$ or N?

So, in order to start to solve it I need to calculate ${(A_{2n} \setminus A_n)}$, but what is ${A_{2n}}$ here?

If ${A_n = \{0, 1, 2, ... n\}}$, so ${A_{2n} = \{0, 2, 4, 6, ... n\}}$, right?

Thus the answer is ${\{2, 4, 6, ... n\}}$, but this answer not in the range of given answers...

What I am missing?

Comment: $A_{2n}$ is $A_{(2n)}$.

Comment: $A_{2n}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,2n\}$, so $A_{2n}\setminus A_n=\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove:
for all n > 0, exists k > 0 with k < n <= 2k.
Thus
for all n > 0, exists k with n in A$_n$ - A$_{2n}$.
Consequently N - {0} subset U = $\cup_n$(A$_n$ - A$_{2n}$).
Show 0 not in U.  Conclude U = N - {0}.